# What is .icloud format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, icloud-drive

i appiled iCloud Storage.

i searched iCloud folder(in documentsDirectory).

```
NSURL *ubiquityContainer [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSURL *documentsDirectory = [ubiquityContainer URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentsDirectory includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 error:nil];
```

directoryContent has URL list.
and i found strange URL.

if file name is aa.pptx
, this URL is '~/.aa.pptx.icloud'

what is .icloud format?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an Apple created file extension. It shouldn't cause you any problems.